# Formular dragging in Excel

Tags: excel, cell

I have a data of 1000 rows in Excel, and I wish to calculate the variance  of every 10 data, say `=var.s(A1:A10), =var.s(A11:A20), ....`.
I did the first two manually and tried to drag the formulas down, but instead of having `=var.s(A21:A30), =var.s(A31:A40)` I had `=var.s(A3:A12),  =var.s(A13:A22)`.

Could anyone please suggest how I can get my desired results?

Comment: If you copy and paste the formulas will be adjusted automatically, but if you drag they won't.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I still have the same problem with the copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your values are in ColA you can use a formula like the one shown below: for each row you drag it down it will offset the range fed to VAR.S by 10 rows.

[image]

Comment: I am very grateful for your assistance, it works just fine, though I wasn't patience enough, I wrote a code for it on R software. Nevertheless, this will surely save my time next time.